# Etymology of the "Rats!" exclamation

Tags: etymology

> rat
>
> (...)
>
> 1. rats, *Slang* . (an exclamation of disappointment, disgust, or
>      disbelief.)

(source: [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rat))

Where does this meaning/usage of "rat" come from?

Comment: Rats! I always thought it was 'bats!'

Comment: Not particularly scholarly, but the use of "Rats" as an exclamation came into popular use in the Fifties, with a good deal of help from Scultz's Charlie Brown cartoon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Drat* is first used in the early 19th century as shortening of *od rat*, which was an euphemism for *God rot*.

*Rats* seems a shortening of *od rat* obtained by removing *od*, and used as plural to make it seems the plural of *rat* (the rodent).

**<sub>[Reference: the New Oxford American Dictionary.]</sub>**

Answer (score 3):

Rats have a very negative image in the mind of people, and have had for long (I believe it started with 19th century’s urbanisation, and later intensified; earlier tales of rats feature them as rather nice animals living in fields).

They're typically associated with filth, bad smell, and have be blamed for transmitting diseases. This gave rise to a number of expressions, including “to smell a rat” and the associated meaning of rat (“a person regarded as despicable”). I believe this same popular perception of the animal is responsible for the interjection.

Comment: According to the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=rat&searchmode=none), "interjection rats is Amer.Eng., 1886."

Comment: @Bruno: Merriam-Webster has the same year, but no reference

Comment: But I wonder why **mice**, unlike rats, seem to have such positive image in the mind of people. Think of Mickey Mouse, Jerry (from Tom and Jerry), Fievel and other famous characters.

Comment: Lost the D in Drat? GoD rot 'Drot, Drat, Rat, Rats